# How to remote boot from bios and install an operating system from local USB

Tags: remote, keyboard-video-mouse, intel

So we have a bunch of systems distributed across a semi-large area and are looking to upgrade soon. We are looking for systems that could preferably be booted from a USB drive in the system remotely. I've seen things referencing IP KVMs and vPro to allow remote access at the BIOS level. Is this indeed possible and what would be required for this to happen? In the ideal situation we could:

- Have user plug in USB
- Reboot system from our office
- Boot to the USB into Linux installer
- Go through install dialog

We are looking for a mini-ITX solution (custom build is ok). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? You want to reboot machines and start an installer on a USB drive you've had the user plug in? Or you're looking for new systems to sell to your customers?

Comment: We're looking to reboot machines and start the installer. They are all on the same network and vlan but occasionally crash in such a way that a reinstall is needed and being able to do this remotely would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For something like what you're describing you really want to invest in systems that have [iLO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Integrated_Lights-Out), IPMI with KVM-over-LAN, or equivalent.

Most of these systems also offer remote CD-ROM over the IPMI/KVM connection, which can eliminate the need to distribute USB drives to all your locations (if a machine needs a reinstall you can do the whole thing over the network with the latest boot image).

Picking the hardware is something you'll have to do for yourself (there's a lot of options, built-in and aftermarket), but that's the basic feature set you want.

Comment: Would something like RealVNC VNC Viewer Plus with a vPro compatible processor work?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried for instance installing AnyDesk on Hiren's Boot PE.  Can't get the remote control software install to survive a reboot.  We've decided to go the IP KVM route.  Raritan was waaay to spendy, so we built a PiKVM.
(https://pikvm.org/).  Cost was around $250 CDN and it does much of what we need. Struggling with remote BIOS access when connecting to laptops, but if you're accessing servers, it's great.  You can connect it to four servers at a time with a eZcoo KVM switch.  Support is via their Discord channel.